# Which is lightest on resources, free and portable MP3 player for Windows with playlist support?

Tags: windows-xp, mp3, portable

Which is lightest on resources, free and portable MP3 player for Windows with playlist support?

I don't need any visualization/plugin/skins.

Please give info about memory usage (while song is running in player) also in your answer.

Comment: Consider making this CW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an older version of Winamp from the 90's ;)

Comment: Definitely, I used a pre-AOL takeover 2.x version of Winamp for years, great little player, did everything I needed and ran with almost no resources. Thank god for http://www.oldversion.com for when you need the pre-bloated versions of great apps!

Comment: u were right Winamp 2.0 is lightest http://www.oldversion.com/download_Winamp_2.00.html

Answer (score 7):

I think [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) suits your needs

[Wikipedia on foobar2000:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar2000)

> foobar2000 is a freeware audio player
>   for Windows developed by Peter
>   Pawlowski, a former freelance
>   contractor for Nullsoft. It is known
>   for its highly modular design and
>   extensive SDK which allows third-party
>   developers to do such things as
>   completely replace the interface.
>   While supporting a large number of
>   audio file formats, it has many
>   features for metadata support and file
>   organization, and it has a converter
>   interface for use with command line
>   encoders. To maximize the audio
>   fidelity of consumer-grade equipment,
>   it provides noise shaping and
>   dithering. It features a number of
>   official and third-party components
>   which add many additional features.
>   While the core is closed source, the
>   SDK is licensed under the BSD license.

[image]

Comment: While it's easy to bloat fb2k with components, the music-playing bit is really very light, so if you want lightness above all, fb2k's your best choice.

Comment: @Phoshi
Agreed, mine has tons of components installed and it consumes around 90 MBs of memory while playing MP3s. I am not complaining though, I love my components :).

Answer (score 4):

[XMPlay](http://www.un4seen.com/) is pretty good. Very lightweight, skinnable, no install needed.

[image]

> XMPlay is an audio player, supporting
>   the OGG / MP3 / MP2 / MP1 / WMA / WAV
>   / AIFF / CDA / MO3 / IT / XM / S3M /
>   MTM / MOD / UMX audio formats, and PLS
>   / M3U / ASX / WAX playlists. A load
>   more formats are also supported via
>   plugins. When XMPlay was first
>   released in 1998, only the XM format
>   was supported, hence the name
>   "XMPlay".

XMPlay is freeware.

Another small and lightweight player is [musikCube](http://www.musikcube.com/), which supports playlists as well as dynamic playlists:

[image]

musikCube is freeware.

Comment: do u know how to make a simple look ox xm play. i don't need any skin.

Comment: and musikCube takes 11 MB RAM even if song is not played. I didn't liked both

Comment: +1 for xmplay. It´s just great. 3,164 KB of memory usage while playing.

Answer (score 3):

Use [1by1](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/1by1.html). It's a free, portable, small (152KB) and light (about 5MB of RAM) audio player.

> Features
>
> - Directory Player: directly plays your folder contents
> - Full Resume play: remembers last track and position
> - Gapless play · simple crossfading · Audio enhancer
> - Folder tree file navigation · Directory finder: plays whole drive
> - Supported decoders: ACM (mp3), mpglib (mp2, mp3)
> - BASS decoder library support (ogg, wav, aac, mp4, cd...)
> - Winamp 2.x input plugin support
> - File utils: copy, move, rename while play, delete, date change
> - Folder compare tool · Rename tool · Big title display
> - Cue sheet support · Playlist support · Favorites
> - Audio scrobbling support · Unicode support
> - Very small size · Low resource usage · portable

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Damn Small Media Player](http://code.google.com/p/dsmp/)

> I know there are loads of mp3 players
>   available, so why one more. The
>   motivation behind me writing this app
>   is that I am fed up with the ever
>   increasing size of mp3 players. This
>   is meant to ease my pain :-P. I aim to
>   keep its size below 2MB at all costs.

Using the player:

- Ctrl+A on the List Ctrl selects all
  the files in the list of files
- Global HotKeys added for
  Previous(Ctrl+Alt+Z),
  Play/Pause(Ctrl+Alt+X),
  Stop(Ctrl+Alt+C) and Next(Ctrl+Alt+V)
- Download the exe and run it. Its that
  simple.
- Click on Add button and select the
  files/folders you want to add to the
  playlist
- Shortcut keys (Z= Previous, X=
  Play/Pause, C = Pause, V= Next)
- Playlist Queue(Select the file and
  click on Insert key to add file to
  queue)

Comment: it'good but it takes approx 20 MB memory while playing songs. is it normal.

Comment: iTunes takes about 30-40 MB, so I suppose its normal

Answer (score 0):

[Media Player Classic Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) meets all your requirements!

Comment: MPC is great, but while far from bloated, I don't think it could be considered one of the lightest. Not for just MP3 anyway.

Comment: @outsideblasts - u r right

Answer (score 0):

[Winamp Lite](http://www.winamp.com/media-player/free.php) (you can find it at the bottom of the page). It's small (~3MB), light on resources and familiar. Has everything you might need just for playing music. If you want to extend its functionality, you can do it through plugins.

Answer (score 0):

[musikcube](http://www.musikcube.com/) is a fantastic light media player. Although the last update was in 2006, I haven't really found any features lacking.

[image]